# Getting some adult sites as popup window

Tags: windows-7, internet, browser, browser-addons, popups

I am using windows 7 64 bit, whenever I open new tab in my browser I got open some porn site as pop up window (just like we got adds as pop up window).This happens on almost every minute. All it started after connecting my laptop with my office network. So please tell me the solution for this.

Comment: You have malware installed on your computer.  You should remove it using software like Malwarebytes.

Comment: I scan for malware, I got some but with low risk. Still I clean them but it doesn't help

Answer (score -3):

Your browser is infected by spyware, adware, malware or other stuff like this.
The clean things up, you should download and install super anti spyware from here https://www.superantispyware.com and run a complete system scan.
Also, if you use IE or FF they may be very affected by the above.
Try to download opera and use that one. It will be clean and is very hard to get infected.
You should also set your homepage to a blank one, it may link to undesired sites.

Comment: Why would Opera be more malware-proof than other browsers?

Comment: Primary because it is the most secure browser in the world. Your question is illogical. Its like asking why a car would be faster than another. its a known fact that FF always had the most security holes and that IE infects most easy.

Comment: Any citations for this statement? As opposed to cars, browsers are free, so I guess the most secure browser would be one of the most popular. Opera is used by merely 1.6% of Internet users. Besides, it's based on Chromium - so is Chrome, which you have silently omitted, even though it's the most popular browser with 48% of users, more than its three biggest competitors *combined* and 30 times more users than Opera. (January 2015 stats from [StatCounter](http://gs.statcounter.com/))

Comment: Well thats exactly it, the most used are the ones that are most exploited. It is logical that if anyone wants to find browser vulnerabilities he will dig in to the most used ones. So the number of low users on Safari and Opera will actually help because the browsers will be less targeted.

Comment: @Overmind - Opera is now based on Chrome.  Where is the proof Opera is better than Firefox, Chrome, or even IE11?  This is 100% opinion not based any factual statistics. At the end of the day at hacking conventions, EVERY SINGLE BROWSER, ends up being compromised.

Comment: Theres proof every year, check the reviews. Also, the new engine of opera is not better than the old one.

Comment: Btw, Opera is not based on chrome. Opera now contributes to the whole Chromium/Blink code. Many users did not agree to the switch, but it did happen in order to standardize more things. Lets not forget who put the basics of HTML5, native video and Media Queries or who invented tabs, speed-dial. While many did not agree to this, it's better overall because the standards can now be improved with otherwise not available features.